# Python How to get the class object from a value within the object

Tags: python

Imagine i have a list of classes like this:

```
people = [[john, 18], [mary, 17], [joe, 13]]
```

And i want to find if there is a person that is 13 years old in my list of class objects and return their name. How would i do this? I found some code to return true if the variables match but how do i return the other values of the object?

Something like the code below. Thanks!

```
if isinstance(13, people): 

    return name, color(etc)
```

Comment: `next(person for person, age in people if age == 13)`…?

Comment: @deceze Although it works for the example, that way you will only find the first person aged 13

Comment: @Nuno Sure. The requirement doesn't say otherwise though… This really isn't a question possible to answer in great detail at this point.

Comment: @deceze You were right after all, the OP only wants the first element :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the name of a person like this:

```
ageToFind = 13
for x in people:
    if(x[1] == ageToFind):
        print(x[0])
```

**EDIT:**

Seeing as the OP requires only the first element (taken from "deceze" comment):

```
print(next(person for person, age in people if age == 13))
```

OR using the previous answer:

```
ageToFind = 13
for x in people:
    if(x[1] == ageToFind):
        print(x[0])
        break
```

Comment: So i need to itarate through EVERY SINGLE instance in the list to find one match? I am working with really huge lists this will be very slow...

Comment: @Austin Yes, you'll need to loop in one way or another. If you want direct access without loop you'll need to organise your data in a different data structure that's more efficient to access in certain ways; e.g group all users by age in a `dict`.

Comment: Got it.. Ill convert these objects into a dict then. Thanks =)